# No response from summer school. Should I email?

Tags: email, summer-school

I have applied to a summer school program in math for undergraduates. On the application website it says that notifications of acceptance or rejection will be sent out in March.
As March is nearly ending and email is the only means for them to contact me I'm wondering whether maybe I should cautiously ask, if my application has already been reviewed ? This is because I'm considering the possibility that maybe something went wrong with the email (yes, I checked my spam folder) and I definitely don't want to miss the summer school just because I didn't respond in time to an email that never made it to me.

(It may be helpful for the answerer to know that on the summer schools website it says that we can send them email in case we have other deadlines so that they can try to decide sooner upon the mailers application.)

Comment: If you're approaching a deadline -- yours or theirs -- you may want to phone instead.

Comment: @keshlam unfortunately no phone number is provided

Comment: You should be able to find a number, with a bit of work. If you can't,  I would seriously question whether they are a legitimate school.

Comment: @keshlam well, I can probably get some phone number of some department faculty, but I'd have no idea how relevant that person would be for the school, so trying that would give a impression of me being somewhat desperate, I think, which I wouldn't want...

Comment: The school must have a website,  or a paper catalog, or a letterhead, or some such thing that would give you the main phone number. Or a address which would let you get thenimber from the phone company. Call that and ask to be connected to whoever is In charge of admissions for the program you're interested in. It may take several hops, but you should get there, and none of those hops will consider your call unreasonable. You aren't desperate, you're eager. That's not a negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask. That is, send a polite email inquiring if there is any news.

There's a possibility that the decisions have simply not been made yet - the organizers of the summer school, just like the rest of us, are busy and bad at keeping to deadlines - but it's still okay to ask (politely).

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna do that...though it won't be easy to ask without sounding nosey I think...

Comment: It won't be that bad. Run your email by a trusted fellow student to see how it reads to an outside observer.